# How to configure model activerecord in rails for items with multiple links

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, hyperlink, items

I have two models, Item and Link. Each link is going to join two items together, only two. What is the best way to set up the model relationship?

I currently have this:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many  :links
end


class Link < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :item1, :class_name => "Item", :foreign_key => "item1_name"
  belongs_to :item2, :class_name => "Item", :foreign_key => "item2_name"
end
```

Is this correct? Will I run into any problems later on when I wanted to list the links for each item?

Please recommend me better alternatives, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at has one through

Something like

```
Item

:has_one :item, through: :links
```

That should link two items together through the links model

Comment: hm, nope that's not quite what I was looking for. My items are going to have multiple links to different items.  Each link needs to be an object so that I can tack on ratings to it